# How get a pointer to a value in a map in Go

Tags: go

I would like to get a pointer to a map value (which contains structs), so that I can modify a field in the struct, without having to re-assign it.

```
type Foo struct {
    Bar int64
}

func SomeFunction(arg * Foo) {
    ...
}
```

What I currently have to do:

```
if val, ok := myMap[idx]; ok {
  // val is of type `Foo`
  SomeFunction(&val)
  myMap[idx] = val
}
```

What I'd like to do:

```
if val, ok := getPointer(myMap, idx); ok {
  // val is of type `* Foo`
  SomeFunction(val)
}
```

Is there a way to do this Go, or do I need to rely on the compiler being smart enough to perform copy elision here?

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11865

Comment: What original problem are you solving? Is this copy operation a bottleneck? Have you profiled and checked the go assembly for this code?

Comment: Unduable. Map values are not addressable.

Comment: A solution to the problem may be to use `map[keyType]*Foo`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this operation you may use `map` with pointers. Like:

```
var myMap map[int]*Foo

if _, val := range myMap {
  // val is of type `* Foo`
  SomeFunction(val)
}
```